# Parsing lines one after the other in a XML using PowerShell3.0

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to parse the content under the xml tags one after the other using PowerShell3.0 but I am unable to do it in a desired way. 
The XML looks like this

```
<entry>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Uploads</path> <file>upload.exe</file>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Downloads</path><file>download.exe</file>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Documents</path><file>log_file.log</file>
</entry>
```

The desired output is :

```
C:\Users\Admin\Uploads
upload.exe
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads
download.exe
C:\Users\Admin\Documents
log_file.log
```

The name of xml file is new.xml I am using the following code to just print a path and its respective file in each iteration.

```
$new = Get-Content .\new.xml
$new = [xml]$new
foreach($item in $new.entry){
    $item.path
    $item.file
}
```

But the output I get is :

```
C:\Users\Admin\Uploads
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads
C:\Users\Admin\Documents
upload.exe
download.exe
log_file.exe
```

I even tried editing the XML file like this:

```
<entry>
<details>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Uploads</path> <file>upload.exe</file>
</details>
<details>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Downloads</path><file>download.exe</file>
</details>
<details>
    <path>C:\Users\Admin\Documents</path><file>log_file.log</file>
</details>
</entry>
```

And then tried parsing a path and its file respectively But even this dosent help. Where am I going wrong ? Is there a way I can actually parse one path and its respective file ineach iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML, you have no relation between the `path` and the `file` element. They are simply listed at the same level under `entry`.

```
<entry>
  <path>C:\Users\Admin\Uploads</path>
  <file>upload.exe</file>
  <path>C:\Users\Admin\Downloads</path>
  <file>download.exe</file>
  <path>C:\Users\Admin\Documents</path>
  <file>log_file.log</file>
</entry>
```

If you want to generate your desired output, you can do the following:

```
foreach($item in $new.entry.ChildNodes) {
    $item.InnerText
}
```

But note that this is brittle, the output depends on the **order** of the child nodes. This is poor practice. Your second XML is much better as it clearly expresses the relation between `path` and `file`. You can then easily process each `details` element like so:

```
foreach($d in $new2.entry.ChildNodes){
    echo "The file '$($d.file)' is located at the following path: $($d.path)"
}
```

Comment: Thankyou :) that helped a lot. It occurred that the second XML would be a better design but I didnt know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you probably always have the same number of files and paths in the xml you could do this:

```
$xml = [xml](gc .\new.xml)
$count = $xml.entry.file.Count
if ($count -ne $xml.entry.path.Count) {
    Write-Warning "Mismatched file and path elements. Found $($xml.entry.path.Count) paths and $count files."
}
for($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i += 1) {
    $xml.entry.path[$i]
    $xml.entry.file[$i]
}
```

Your second xml is simpler because the structure is clear. You can do it like this:

```
$xml = [xml](gc .\new2.xml)
$xml.entry.details | foreach { $_.path, $_.file }
```

Comment: An equal number of `path` and `file` elements does not guarantee that their order is consistent. OP's second XML is really the best option.

Comment: @mike z: Yeah in some cases I have just the path but no file in it, so the first one wouldnot work. The second XML is much better so I'm going ahead with that. Thank you so much for the replies :)